# Must you manually create a database in mysql before automigrating from models in loopback?

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I am new to loopbackjs. I am attempting to perform my first automigration of a model to a mysql database. Should I expect that loopback will automatically create the database if it does not yet exist? Or must I always create the database manually using the mysql tools?

Here are some of my files:

**datasource.json** (in server directory)

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "dingobase": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "dingo",
    "password": "***",
    "name": "dingobase",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "insecureAuth": true,
    "debug": true 
  }
}
```

**archetype.json** (in common/models directory)

```
{
  "name": "Archetype",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "ArchetypeID": {
      "type": "number",
      "generated": true,
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**model-config.json** (in server directory)

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Archetype": {
    "dataSource": "dingobase",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

**automigrate.js** (in server/boot)

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.dataSources.dingobase.automigrate();
    console.log("Performed automigration.");
 }
```

When I run "node ." from the command prompt, I get errors:

```
Connection fails: Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'dingo'
It will be retried for the next request.
C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'dingo'
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:130:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at MySQL.connect (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:90:17)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:44:28)
    at DataSource.setup (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:492:19)
    at new DataSource (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:138:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback\lib\registry.js:362:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:560:19)
    at Function.app.dataSource (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:267:14)
    at C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:191:9
    at C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:282:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachKeyedObject (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:281:20)
    at setupDataSources (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:181:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DataSource.postInit (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:479:16)
    at C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:102:19
    at Handshake.onConnect [as _callback] (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:58:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:132:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\pchernoch\projects\LoopbackTest\Dingo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must create the database separately.